# Closed form for $ \prod_{k=1}^n (a+k^2) $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, closed-form, products

I have come across the following product:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^n (a+k^2) $$
where $a$ is a positive constant. Could anyone suggest a closed form for this product? **I need to approximate this for large $n$**, but the problem is that $a$ is also of order of $n$ (it does not change with $n$, but it is also a large number).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** Here is an approach.

Recall that, for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, the [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) may be defined as
$$(z)_n = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (z+k)=z(z + 1)(z + 2) \cdots (z + n - 1), \quad n > 1, \quad (z)_0 = 1.$$
Then, for $a\geq0$, write
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (a+k^2)
&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+i\sqrt{a})\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (k-i\sqrt{a})
=(i\sqrt{a})_n(-i\sqrt{a})_n \quad (i^2=-1)
\end{align}
$$ and the given product may be expressed as

> $$
> \prod_{k=1}^{n} (a+k^2) =(1+i\sqrt{a})_{n}(1-i\sqrt{a})_{n} \tag1
> $$

**Added.** If you write the Pochhammer symbol in terms of the Euler $\Gamma$ function, then $(1)$ rewrites

> $$
> \prod_{k=1}^{n} (a+k^2)\! =\!\frac{\Gamma(n+1+i\sqrt{a})}{\Gamma(i\sqrt{a})}\!\frac{\Gamma(n+1-i\sqrt{a})}{\Gamma(-i\sqrt{a})}\!=\!\left|\Gamma(n+1+i\sqrt{a})\right|^2\frac{\sinh(\pi\sqrt{a})}{\pi\sqrt{a}} \tag2
> $$

as noticed by *Antinous' answer*, where we have used eulerian [infinite products involving $\Gamma$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm).

Then, **as $n$ is great**, by applying Stirling formula (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947219/equivalent-of-xx1x2-cdotsxn/952122#952122) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling.27s_formula_for_the_Gamma_function)), you obtain the following asymptotic term:

> $$
> \prod_{k=1}^{n} (a+k^2) 
> =   \frac{2\pi \: n^{2n+1}e^{-2n}}{|\Gamma(1+i\sqrt{a})|^2}\!\left(\! 1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left(\frac1n\right)\!\right)\! \sim \frac{2\sinh(\pi\sqrt{a})}{\sqrt{a}} n^{2n+1}e^{-2n} \tag3
> $$

Comment: Very nice, thanks!

Comment: How did you use the Stirling formula to get (3)? It seems that you replaced $z=1+n+i\sqrt{a}$ by $n$, are we allowed to do that (since $a$ is also a large number)?

Comment: @Azoodish Yes, we are allowed to do this substitution, since, as you said, $a$ **is independent of** $n$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your product has the nice closed form
$$\prod_{k=1}^n(a+k^2)=\left|\Gamma(n+1+i\sqrt{a})\right|^2\frac{\sinh(\pi\sqrt{a})}{\pi\sqrt{a}}.$$