# hard time coming up with an idea to find a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am solving another problem and it boils down to solving this problem:

We have that $b > a > 0$ are two arbitrary given real numbers.

Let $p_n = \dfrac{a(a+1)...(a+n)}{b(b+1)...(b+n)}$

Prove that

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n = 0$.

Is this true at all?
How do we prove it?

Comment: Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\log p_n - \log p_{n-1}) = -\infty.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Hm, I was hoping for something simpler, more direct. Also, how will this help me conclude what I want? Assume that I only know sequences and series and their respective properties (from a standard university course on mathematical analysis).

Comment: Since $p_n > 0$ for all $n$, we have no problem taking logarithms. Now, $p_n \to 0$ if and only if $\log p_n \to -\infty$. And $$\log p_n = \log \frac{a}{b} + \sum_{k=1}^n (\log p_k - \log p_{k-1}).$$ Then note that $$\log p_k - \log p_{k-1} = \log \frac{p_k}{p_{k-1}} = \log \frac{a+k}{b+k} = \log \frac{1 + \frac{a}{k}}{1 + \frac{b}{k}} = \log \left(1+\frac{a}{k}\right) - \log \left(1 + \frac{b}{k}\right).$$ Using $\log (1+x) = x + O(x^2)$, we have $\log \frac{a+k}{b+k} = \frac{a-b}{k} + O(k^{-2})$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Daniel, thank you. But this is a typical example where people here solve a hard (but introductory) problem through the use of non-introductory (more advanced) apparatus. I mean, seems you use 2-3 things which are not yet introduced/proved in this book I am reading. I am looking for some proof which uses simpler techniques. In the meantime I will think some more about it myself. All these statements which translate the problem to logs is not something I have at hand yet.

Comment: What methods have you at hand? Everything elementary I can come up with uses logarithms resp. the exponential function.

Comment: @DanielFischer Assume I know sequences, limits, series, conditional/absolute convergence of series, tests for convergence of series with non-negative members, alternating series tests. Assume also I know the definition of e as limit of $(1+1/n)^n$. Assume I know nothing about functions yet, and their limits, etc.

Comment: Nothing about the exponential function, $e^{x+y} = e^x\cdot e^y$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} e^x = 0$? These would suffice. You can get the addition theorem for the exponential function - and from that the required limit - from either the definition of $e^x$ as a power series, $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!},$$ or as the limit $e^x = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$. If one could use that, it would make for a shorter proof than proving these things too.

Comment: @DanielFischer No, these are not introduced yet. But OK, thanks. I will think about it all. Thanks.

Comment: Peter, take a look at the answer I've just posted. I think it is rather elementary, and, even more importantly, correct. :D

Comment: I think you would like to know that, Using the Raabe,s test we can prove that the series $\sum p_n$ is convergent if and only if $b\gt a+1.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} p_n = 0$, we can, since $p_n > 0$ for all $n$, show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{p_n} = +\infty$.

Rewriting in a convenient manner, we obtain

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{p_n} &= \prod_{k=0}^n \frac{b+k}{a+k}\\
&= \prod_{k=0}^n \biggl(1 + \frac{b-a}{a+k}\biggr).
\end{align}

Now we use that for $x_k \geqslant 0$ we have

$$\prod_{k=0}^n (1 + x_k) \geqslant 1 + \sum_{k=0}^n x_k.\tag{$\ast$}$$

The inequality $(\ast)$ is easily proved by induction. Using $(\ast)$, we deduce

$$\frac{1}{p_n} \geqslant 1 + \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{b-a}{a+k}.\tag{1}$$

Comparison with the harmonic series shows that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{b-a}{a+k} = +\infty,$$

and hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} p_n = 0$.

Comment: Wow, that's really nice and simple. Thanks! That is the solution I needed.

Answer (score 2):

One may recall that, as $n \to +\infty$, by the [generalized Stirling formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947219/equivalent-of-xx1x2-cdotsxn/952122#952122), we have
$$
a(a+1)(a+2)\cdots(a+n) \sim  \frac{n^{n+a}e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n} }{\Gamma(a)} 
$$
giving $$
 p_n = \frac{a(a+1)...(a+n)}{b(b+1)...(b+n)} \sim  \frac{n^{n+a}e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n} }{\Gamma(a)}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(b) }{n^{n+b}e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}}
$$ that is, as $n \to +\infty$: $$
 p_n = \frac{a(a+1)...(a+n)}{b(b+1)...(b+n)} \sim  \frac{\Gamma(b) }{\Gamma(a)}n^{a-b} \to 0,
$$ since $0<a<b$.

Comment: Thanks, but I definitely don't have all this knowledge after reading the first 2-3 first chapters of the book I am reading.

Comment: @peter.petrov What book are you reading?  Maybe it would help to provide this context in the question, so that responses can adapt to it.

Comment: @ErickWong Assume I know sequences, limits, series, conditional/absolute convergence of series, tests for convergence of series with non-negative members, alternating series tests. Assume also I know the definition of e as limit of $(1+1/n)^n$. Assume I know nothing about functions yet, and their limits, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}p_n.$ If $b\ge a+1$ the following inequalities hold: $$\require\cancel 0<p_n\le \frac{a\cancel{(a+1)\cdots(a+n)}}{\cancel{(a+1)(a+2)\cdots(a+n)}(a+1+n)}=\frac{a}{a+1+n}\to0,$$ and thus $L=0$ by the squeeze theorem.

For the case $b<a+1$, note that since for any positive $m$ $$\frac{a}{b}<\frac{a+m}{b+m},$$ we have $$L\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a+n}{b+n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a-b}{b+n}\right)^n=e^{a-b}<1.$$ Now suppose $L>0$. Then, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n^{p_n}=L^L<1\tag{$\star$}.$$ But $$\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n^{p_n}\ge\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a\cancel{(a+1)\cdots(a+n)}}{\cancel{(a+1)(a+2)\cdots(a+n)}(a+1+n)}\right)^{\frac{a\cancel{(a+1)\cdots(a+n)}}{\cancel{(a+1)(a+2)\cdots(a+n)}(a+1+n)}} \\ \lim_{n\to\infty}p_n^{p_n}\ge\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a}{a+1+n}\right)^{\frac{a}{a+1+n}}=1,$$ which contradicts $(\star)$. Therefore, $L=0$.

Comment: Thanks. There're 2 steps or so here which I am not convinced about (don't think they follow rigorously from what I know; I am not saying they are wrong though; I am just not sure). Thanks anyway.

Comment: @peter Which steps?

Comment: How did you get the last inequality e.g.?! Also, is there a theorem saying that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$ then $a_n^{a_n} -> L^L$ ?!

Comment: @peter It follows from $b<a+1$. If $a_n\not\to 0$, that follows from the continuity of the function $x^x$ in $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: OK, I see (about the last inequality). As I said, probably the proof is alright, it's my lack of knowledge or imagination, I guess :)

Comment: As I said, assume I don't know about functions yet. Not to talk about continuity of functions. I mean, I know about those but they are not yet introduced in this book.

Comment: @peter Well, they are topics dealt with earlier than, e.g., the harmonic series and in general infinite series. :)

Comment: Not in my book. The book first introduces sequences, then series, then functions and their continuity, derivatives, etc. I am just rereading this book which I studied in university 16-17 years ago. Anyway, keep the answer here, it's a pretty smart proof, I think. Thanks once again.

Comment: @peter Uh, quite interesting! Alright, you're welcome.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva great answer

Comment: @DomenicoVuono: Thank you! :D